# Help with Vehicle Service database

Tags: database-design, ms-access

I am using the Desktop Vehicle Maintenance template in access, but i am trying to cater it towards our farms needs.

We will be keeping track of the service's done on Trucks, Tractors, Equipment, etc.
Each Vehicle will have different fields and different data tracked. But i can't figure out how to create a table for each entity and pull it into one centralized table to display service's done on all vechiles/equipment.

Comment: Can you please provide the table structure that you already use and your needed column so I can figure out your requirement ...

Answer (score 1):

> But i can't figure out how to create a table for each entity and pull it into one centralized table

It sounds like you want to read up on Joins: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

A "join" basically lets you have a query that returns data from multiple tables, based on some criteria, such as records in two tables having a certain matching value. If you want to give the appearance of having this combined data all in one table, you could create a View ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28database%29 ) of the query with all the joins. MS Access lets you use views to drive reports as easily as it lets you use tables for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need a vehicles table and a vehicles properties table. The vehicles table would include all fields that vehicles have in common, such as type, make, registration and vehicle properties would include additional properties specific to each vehicle.

```
VehicleID -- foreign key to vehicles
Property -- or property ID
PropertyValue
```

Table Example

```
VehicleID Property         Value
   1      Has Blah         Yes
   1      Blah Size        234
   24     Last Blah Date   24/7/2007
```

If maintenance refers to the various properties, you can create the maintenance table with foreign keys to the vehicle ID and the property ID and add the maintenance fields, such as date, mechanic etc, if maintenance refers to the overall vehicle, the maintenance table can be related to the vehicles table.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses guys! I think however i am going to use a different table for each entity such as Truck, Tractor, Equipment, because there is just to many differences in what needs to be tracked.